# Modificando altura do campo text mantendo o 'foco' do campo no topo

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, estou com uma dúvida simples, fiz algumas pesquisas e não consegui encontrar nada relacionado, eu não quero acreditar que isso é um 'bug'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, a digitação do campo inicia somente no meio do mesmo, não importa quantos padding ou margin eu dou internamente, a ideia é usar um campo typeahead com altura alterada com a digitação no lugar certo, infelizmente nesse caso não consigo usar um 'textarea' e usar o atributo "rows", preciso que seja no campo text...

Então, alguém sabe como eu mudo isso ? Grato desde já !
Obs: Desculpe a pergunta 'noob'. rs

Comment: Sem usar `padding-bottom: 100px`?

Comment: Porque tem a necessidade de ser dentro de um input e não em um textarea? Fiz um teste aqui com padding, e funcionou de boa, o problema é que ele não vai pular para a segunda linha quando chegar ao limite da primeira, sempre vai se estender horizontalmente.

Comment: Paulo, porque como você pode vê na descrição eu uso um typeahead, é um campo texto que utiliza umas ferramentas de busca.

Comment: Thiago Santos, o padding-bottom resolveu a posição, mas me criou outro problema que é a quebra de linha ao chegar no final do campo, será que não tem nenhum meio de simular um textarea usando um text? T_T

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha nisso aqui: https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete e talvez a abordagem mais correta seja: **Como usar Typeahead com Textarea**?

Comment: É, você tem razão, obrigado ! Irei excluir o tópico para não ficar "manchando" a comunidade com coisas inúteis.

Comment: Por que vc acha que é inútil ? @LincolnBinda, Eu considero uma dúvida que qualquer pessoa que tiver iniciando pode ter... Inclusive se encontrar a solução e postar uma resposta você estaria enriquecendo a comunidade ainda mais...

Comment: @LincolnBinda Até onde eu sei, só com `padding-bottom` mesmo.